# Spring boot GraphQL showing 404

Tags: spring-boot, api, graphql, graphiql

I am new to GraphQL. However, after watching couple of videos and GraphQL blogs I decided to give it a try but I am getting "404 error" even after doing exactly the same thing as in those videos/blogs. Could this be because of "I am using a little newer version of Spring Boot than in those videos/blogs". Even this bare-bone example: https://github.com/shressur/spring-boot-and-graphql is not working. I would appreciate if anyone could guide me to the right direction.

QueryResolver.java

```
package com.example.demo.resolver;
import graphql.kickstart.tools.GraphQLQueryResolver;

public class QueryResolver implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

   public String testingApp(){
       return "Test in progress...";
   }

}
```

learngraphql.graphqls

```
schema {
   query: Query
}
type Query{
   testingApp: String
}
```

dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.graphql</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-graphql-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>11.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

accessing graphiql:

```
http://localhost:8080/graphiql
```

query:

```
query{
     testingApp
}
```

error:

```
{
   "timestamp": "2022-05-01T17:49:04.825+00:00",
   "status": 404,
   "error": "Not Found",
   "path": "/graphql"
}
```

Comment: Adding `@Component` on the `QueryResolver` solved the issue (testing API successfully via Postman)

Answer (score 1):

Adding **@Component** on the **QueryResolver** solved the issue (testing API successfully via Postman)